# Apply Different WHERE clause depending on value of one field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

i'm trying to build a query in which I need to apply 2 different where clauses, depending on the value of Current Month. In this case, I need to show data from the last 2 years, only of the months before the current month:

### Example 1:

Current Date is: `01-01-2017`

Need to show data from:

```
01/2015; 02/2015; 03/2015; 04/2015; 05/2015; 06/2015;
07/2015; 08/2015; 09/2015; 10/2015; 11/2015; 12/2015;
01/2016; 02/2016; 03/2016; 04/2016; 05/2016; 06/2016;
07/2016; 08/2016; 09/2016; 10/2016; 11/2016; 12/2016.
```

### Example 2:

Current Date is: `01-03-2017`

Need to show data from: `01/2016; 02/2016; 01/2017; 02/2017.`

So I built the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE
    CASE MONTH(GETDATE())
        WHEN 1
        THEN YEAR(Data)>=YEAR(GETDATE())-2 and YEAR(data)<YEAR(GETDATE())
        ELSE YEAR(Data)>=YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and YEAR(data)<=YEAR(data) and MONTH(data)<MONTH(GETDATE())
    END
```

I'm getting an error. 
Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: diin, I guess this is supposed to be treated as pseudo code

Comment: I'm getting the error: Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect for sure. `THEN` is not a logical expression - it is supposed to return `value`. So you can't write logical expression in `THEN`/`ELSE` blocks as you have attempted to. Instead you might try something like:

```
WHERE 
  @date >= CASE WHEN a=b THEN '20150101' ELSE '20160202' END
```

Another thing is: conversions and functions in predicate are very bad for performance. When working with dates you might want to prepare filter predicate before the query when possible, e.g.:

```
declare
  @date_begin date,
  @date_end date

set @date_end = DATEADD(..., @arg_date)
set @date_begin = DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @date_end)

select ...
where date between @date_begin and @date_end
```

in your case it could be something like:

```
declare
    @arg_date   DATE = GETDATE(),
    @date_begin DATE,
    @date_end   DATE,
    @max_month  INT

set @max_month = MONTH(@date)

if @max_month = 1
begin
    set @date_end = DATEADD(dd, 1-DATEPART(dy, @arg_date), @arg_date) /* first day of year */
    set @date_begin = dateadd(YY, -2, @date_end)
end
else
begin
    set @date_end = @arg_date
    set @date_begin = dateadd(YY, -1, DATEADD(dd, 1-DATEPART(dy, @date_end), @date_end)) /* first day of year_begin */
end

SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t
WHERE t.date >= @date_begin and t.date < @date_end
    AND (@max_month = 1 OR MONTH(t.date) < @max_month)
```

another (a better) way is to prepare `@periods` table variable, put each `(date_begin, date_end)` pair you need into it and join with `TABLE1` - you'll get rid of all function calls from within `WHERE` clause.

You should realize: you know exactly which periods of each year you need in the result set. There is nothing to compute from stored `TABLE1->date` column. Just filter it with precomputed date intervals. Don't convert or modify `date` column - it is already ready to use. Merely apply appropriate filters. `MONTH(date) <= 3` is `date <= 20170331`. Don't torture left part - prepare appropriate right part of such predicates.

Comment: When avoiding the use of functions as per the second script in my answer, where is the performance hit?

Comment: Firstly, both scripts from your answer are unable to provide result set as required in `Example 2`. Take a look at month filter.

Comment: Logic adjusted.  You are yet to point out the performance issues though?  If anything, yours would probably perform worse as you are using the non-SARGable `MONTH(t.date) < @max_month`  which will remove the ability to use indexes etc.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding - I did not see your answer until you pointed on it and did not realize you that are talking not about the original code from the question. You are not making computations on the data so - yes - constants will persist constants. Unfortunately I still can not agree with term "huge overkill" in the context of several trivial operations which are absolutely common in sql programming scenarios. And I guess you missed my final suggestions for the PO. And, yes - constant `-1`, `-2`, `-3` and so on may work faster then @ with periods, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE
    (YEAR(Data)>=YEAR(GETDATE())-2 and YEAR(data)<YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1)
OR  (YEAR(Data)>=YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and MONTH(data)<MONTH(GETDATE()) and MONTH(GETDATE()) <> 1)
```

(Note I removed the superfluous `and YEAR(data)<=YEAR(data)`.).

Personally I prefer (and I think it's generally advised) `AND/OR` logic to a `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause.

The error with your `CASE` statement is caused by the fact that `CASE` returns an atomic value. It cannot be used in the same way as `if` in procedural languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't swap in additional statements to your `where` clause using `case` statements.  Instead, you need to resolve the `case` to an equality:

```
select *
from Table1
where case month(getdate())    -- You want to avoid using functions on fields in your WHERE claises, as this can reduce performance.
        when 1 then case when Data >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate())-2,0)
                           and Data < dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate()),0)
                         then 1    -- Data rows the meet the criteria will return 1.
                         else 0    -- Data rows that do not will return 0.
                         end
        else case when (Data >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate())-1,0)
                        and Data < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())-12,0)
                       )
                       or (Data >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate()),0)
                           and Data < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)
                          )
               then 1
               else 0
               end
        end = 1             -- Then limit the results to only those rows that returned a 1.
```

In your specific instance however, this can be simplified to a standard `or`:

```
select *
from Table1
where (month(getdate()) = 1
         and Data >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate())-2,0)
         and Data < dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate()),0)
      )
   or (month(getdate()) <> 1
         and (Data >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate())-1,0)
              and Data < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())-12,0)
             )
          or (Data >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate()),0)
              and Data < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)
             )
      )
```

Note the use of brackets above to separate out the logical tests.  Where a Data row meets either one of those criteria it will be returned in your query.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I'm still getting error: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @TiagoMaia  Ah apologies, I was missing an `end`, which has now been put in.  I would recommend you use the second script though.